# Can I use new NUnit APIs from a Xamarin.Android unit test app?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, xamarin.android, nunit

I'm currently writing a Xamarin.Android unit test app with NUnit / VS2017. I am using the version of NUnit provided by Xamarin that was automatically referenced when I created my project, namely NUnitLite. Its assembly, `Xamarin.Android.NUnitLite`, appears to be a framework assembly rather than a NuGet package, and I can't uninstall it.

I'm wondering, am I stuck with whatever NUnit APIs Xamarin chose to put in NUnitLite? I want to write

```
Assert.That(expected, Does.StartWith(actual));
```

But it looks like [that was added in NUnit v3](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/commit/5c747d8a8fa28a4c32fc5e0be24297d5082ce8f3), and the `Does` class doesn't even exist in NUnitLite. Does this mean I have to write

```
Assert.IsTrue(expected.StartsWith(actual));
```

instead?

Comment: Yes, if you use the Xamarin unit test project. To use NUnit 3 - I'd recommend considering the NUnit org's own xamarin test runner instead. See: https://github.com/nunit/nunit.xamarin (Full disclaimer: I contribute to this project!)

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin uses a forked version of the original NUnitLite 0.7 or 1.0. (They actually started using it at version 0.7, and I'm not sure if it got updated to 1.0.)

That NUnitLite (which is still available from the NUnit project on GitHub) was a framework and matches approximately the features of NUnit 2.4 - 2.5. The notion of fluent, constraint-based tests originated in NUnitLite and was eventually added to NUnit itself.

With NUnit 3, we eliminated the distinction between "Lite" and "Full" nunit. The extra code that allowed NUnitLite to be used with self-executing test assemblies was refactored into a separate package and we called that "NUnitLite."

In retrospect, the renaming was a mistake. It's obviously confusing to have two NUnitLites out there, one of them a framework and the other not! At this point, however, I'm not sure there is much to do about it.

The alternative to using the Xamarin runner and test is to use NUnit and NUnitLite 3.x. Another option is to use the NUnit Xamarin runner, which is however not yet fully stable.